# How to make polymer app-grid clickable

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, grid-layout

How to make polymer grid item can be act as "a href" like in material design specification (primary action)? This is the link to material design spec: https://material.google.com/components/grid-lists.html#grid-lists-content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-layout?active=app-grid)? You can use a `div` as  container for a number of `a` links like so:

```
<dom-module id="grid-test">
  <template>
    <style include="app-grid-style">
      :host {
        --app-grid-columns: 3;
        --app-grid-item-height: 100px;
      }

      div {
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
      }

      .item {
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="app-grid">
      <a href="#" class="item">1</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">2</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">3</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">4</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">5</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">6</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">7</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">8</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">9</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">10</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">11</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">12</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">13</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">14</a>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "grid-test"
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Hi Ben. Thank you, it solve my problem. I've read the doc for many times, but I missed this statement: "Then, add the class app-grid to a container such as ul or div".